# Text animation on top of an image using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking for a way to animate text on top of an image. For example, http://www.ezbusinesslenders.com/ has a flash animation with text that flys in from the left. I would like to do something similar without using flash. I was thinking of taking several images and putting them in a carousel but I need some suggestions on how to handle the text animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [Sequence.js](http://www.sequencejs.com/)

Edit:
Here are some good demos of Sequence.js doing some similar things to what you're looking for, from their website:

 - [Apple Style Theme](http://www.sequencejs.com/themes/apple-style/)

 - [Modern Slide In](http://www.sequencejs.com/themes/modern-slide-in/)

These examples may be a bit overkill for what you're looking for, but you can download the code and sift through the parts you need. Here is also a link to their documentation, which is very thorough: http://www.sequencejs.com/developers/documentation/#how-sequences-animations-work (I linked to the 'how-it-works' part).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @JasonAller Thanks, I updated my answer with some examples. Since the question wasn't about a problem with code I tried to link to places that were close to what OP looking for. (Although they're all from the same site, so hopefully they don't change that.)

Answer (score 0):

Your most basic approach would be the [Wowslider](http://wowslider.com) or [Flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) add ons.

Comment: Wowslider is a Windows/Mac application which seems suspect when talking about html/web development, however, the effects are what I am looking for...just in a jQuery plugin